# Computing the probability of a collection summing above a given number.

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a sequence of numbers $x_1, x_2,x_3...,x_{49}$ where $x_i \in [12..17]$.

To compute something like the probability of getting the maximum value I can perform a calculation like $p=(\frac{1}{6})^{49}$ because there is only one permutation which will produce the value.

While I somewhat understand that the probability of an arbitrary $k$ hinges on the number of permutations for which $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{49}{x_i}=k$ is true, I'm uncertain how to generalize this.

For the sum $17*49-1$ is the same probability but $17*49-2$ is $p=(\frac{1}{6})^{48}*\frac{2}{6}$ as in the first case we only obtain the sum by 48 17's and 1 16 but the second sum can be obtained by 48 17's and 1 15 or by 47 17's and 2 16's.  It is clear that the ordering is not important.

When we start asking about general values though my brief look at partition number theory  seems to indicate that there is no algebraic solution but there is an efficient recursive solution (I only noted a reference to its existence).

Can anyone provide some insight as to what leap I need to make be able to compute the probability of arbitrary values of $k$?

Comment: If I'm reading correctly what you want to do, I think you want to look at "generating functions". (To be clear, "what I think you want to do" is "find the probability that the sum is $k$, for $k$ some number between $12\times49$ and $17\times49$".)

Comment: Yes, I believe that you have it correct.  I'll see if I can make heads and tails of your solution (no pun inteneded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's treat your problem as the probability of rolling a sum of $k$ in 49 throws of a die with sides labeled $12, 13, \dots, 17$.

A nice way to compute such things is by using a generating function.

Let $P=\frac{1}{6}(x^{12}+x^{13}+\cdots+x^{17})$.

Then the probability of rolling a sum of $k$ in $n$ throws is the coefficient on $x^k$ in the polynomial $P^{n}$.

Using a CAS, this is easily found.

For example, with PARI/GP, I find
       `polcoeff(sum(i=12,17,1/6*x^i)^49,600)`
is equal to $$\frac{77671850837}{7484085902451519080029070374597558272}.$$
This is the probability that your sequence will sum to 600.

To calculate the probability that the sum is above some value $K$, you can just calculate the probability of achieving exactly $k$ for $k>K$ and sum.

Comment: I'm certain I don't understand but I'm going to start with reproducing and go from there.  Are you saying that $P^{49}=(\frac{1}{6}(x^{12}+x^{13}+...+x^{17})^{49})$ and that the coefficient on the expanded polynomial of $x^{600}$ is my probability?  (Clearly not going to attempt that by hand but I'm trying to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Yes, except that your $P^49$ is not quite right: the 49 exponent needs to be outside the parenthesis.

Comment: Ok I see now.  Do you know how I can get PARI/GP to return the result as a decimal?  And thank you for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome!  One way to get a decimal is to multiply the fraction by "1.".  If you run into computational issues (as the rational fractions can involve quite a lot of digits), you can use, for example "1./6" in place of 1/6 and then everything will be calculated as a decimal approximation instead of exactly.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, one last addition, is there a simple way to modify this to say "What is the probability that the sum is at least k?" instead of exactly k (I assume this would be $\sum\limits_{i=49*12}^{k}x_i$ where $x_i$ are from the above calculation)

Comment: @Stephen I'm not sure what you are asking.  The probability that the sum is exactly $k$ is the coefficient on $x^k$ in $P^49$.  To get 'at least $k$', you sum the coefficients from $k$ on up. I'm not sure I've addressed your question.

Comment: I found a way to accomplish it using a Pari/GP for loop, thanks for all your help :)